# Getting null using request.getParameter(abc) when it loads for the first time

Tags: jsp, request

When I call request.getParameter("paramname") in my jsp program giving me null when the page first loads.After submitting again to the same page giving me the correct value.why first time I am getting null?

Comment: Post your jsp & servlet code

Answer (score 0):

For the first time when the page loads you are doing a get request, if you are not appending the `paramname` with your url like below then it will be displayed as null only

```
http://serverurl?paramname=paramvalue
```

In the second time during submission, you will have the `paramname` some where in your asp like below. The form data are bundled during submission and you are getting the value instead of null.

```
<input name="paramname" type="hidden" value="paramvalue">
```

Comment: How to avoid getting null for the first time.Because I am using the returned value in if() condition.If it returns null for the first time then my entire program gets disturbed and gives me wrong output.How to avoid getting null for the first time itself?

Comment: If request parameter is null, then assign a default value in the top of jsp. Like `if(request.getParameter("paramname")==null){paramname = "default param value";}`. Thats how we are dealing it in our environment